# Как решить коллизию имен модулей в python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Добрый день, пытаюсь поставить https://github.com/hackappcom/iloot в docker контейнер с Mac через монтирование и там есть папка **crypto** в которой есть файл **aes.py**, где происходит вот такой импорт:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

Интерпретатор python возвращает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Cipher
```

А происходит это из за того, что интерпретатор пытается найти модуль Cipher в папке `crypto` из за того что os в mac регистронезависима, а должен искать по адресу `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.pyc`.

Если переименовать папку `crypto` в `cryptos` то все работает, но изменять чужой код не хотелось бы, потому что я столкнусь с проблемой обновления.

Как возможно решить данную проблему? Возможно ли при импорте включить регистрозависимость?

Comment: Хмм, попробовать импортировать по полному пути? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: простите за глупый вопрос, но вы установили requirements.txt? `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: По-хорошему надо файлы репозитории подвигать и setup.py прописать, а сейчас там всё кривое

Comment: Да, requirements установлены, иначе бы переименование папки не помогло.

Comment: @NickFelliks видимо этот пакет был где то установлен ранее. Попробуйте создать virtual environment и установить пакет в нем.

Comment: @Barton кажется что все же проблема в ОС. Я использую докер контейнер в который монтируется python код с Mac. И эта проблема с регистрами проявляется только в смонтированной папке.

virtual environment не помог решить эту проблему.

Comment: @NickFelliks снова глупый вопрос, извините :D Но вы устанавливаете пакет в контейнере и пытаетесь запустить код тоже в контейнере?

Comment: @Barton да установка окружения и интерпритатора происходит внутри контейнера, сам исходный код через docker-compose volume монтируется в контейнер из mac.

В смотнтированной директории выполнение этих двух команд равнозначны `cd some_folder` и `cd SoMe_FoLdEr`. Если выйти за пределы смонтированной папки то регистрозависимость снова работает.

Похоже это дурацкое стечение обстоятельств когда окружение и код не расчитаны друг на друга, видимо прийдется либо не монтировать код а устанавливать его при сборке контейнера либо изменять чужой код. 

Сейчас ищу другие варианты обхода  проблемы.

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto')` — адский костыль, но будет работать.

Comment: Немного более нормальное решение — отправить в iloot PR, добавляющий везде `from __future__ import absolute_import`. Но обычно такие пуллреквесты не очень любят (а в вашем случае похоже и не примут — библиотека последний раз обновлялась в 2016 году).

Comment: Было принято решение просто сделать форк библиотеки и исправить коллизию имен путем переименования. Все равно последнее обновление было весьма давно.

Спасибо за помощь =)

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю ,что если есть `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.pyc` file ,то есть и `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py`
Тогда ,не очень красиво ,но  решающий задачу код:

```
def importAES():
    f = open("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.pyc",'r')
    exec(f.read())
    f.close()
    print("Congratulation! You've done it")
importAES()
#Your stuff is going here
...
```